# Most straightforward method of getting an NSArray to an NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsarray, nsarraycontroller

This is a very basic question but I'm struggling to find the answer. I have an `NSManagedObject` called **iSelectedObject**.

Supposing I have a condition later on that pulls either `representedObject` from an `NSOutlineView` or `selectedObjects` from an `NSArrayController`, depending on (irrelevant to this question) criteria, I then need to run a method that requires an `NSManagedObject` to be fed to it. This works fine when I feed it the `representedObject` from the `NSOutlineView` - it's naturally an `NSManagedObject` when picked out this way. However, if I grab the `selectedObjects` of my `NSArrayController`, it's an `NSArray` and I can't feed it to my method.

I'm aware that an `NSArray` can contain `NSManagedObjects` and feel the solution maybe as simple as going one level deeper into my `NSArray` or something similar but how would I feed my `NSArray` to my method that requires and `NSManagedObject`. Should I extract/convert it in some way?

(As a help: The reason that I was even trying to feed the method the `NSArray` is because it and the, alternative, `NSManagedObject` both have the same data held inside. ie, if I make two functions exactly the same with one expecting an `NSArray` and one expecting an `NSManagedObject`, they work perfectly. The only reason I have separate choices of picking out an `NSArray` or `NSManagedObject` is because that seems to be the default that `selectedObjects` and `representedObject` spit out, respectively. If I could pull out one or the other for both, that would be the perfect solution but I'm unsure how to.)

Comment: So what does this mysterious method do that works on both an array and a single object? If you'd show us the code, it would be much easier to understand the problem you are having. If it doesn't matter which type you pass to the method, you could just declare the argument as type `id` and you're done.

Comment: Aha! I think `id` may well do the trick! Thanks! I'd been going too specific and avoiding `id` for so long now that I didn't even think of using it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to change the method to expect a type `id` rather than an `NSManagedObject` and this stopped it complaining.

Answer (score 1):

If the NSArray only contains one object, you could just pull the NSManagedObject out of the NSArray with

```
[array lastObject];
```

If there are multiple objects, run through the array and test each object with

```
[object isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]];
```

Either way, that will give you an NSManagedObject that you can use for your method.

Comment: Thanks. Not applicable to this specific situation but it usually would be and it's a good answer.